# Respond to LocalNotification in viewController

Tags: ios5, ios6, uilocalnotification

I need to respond to a LocalNotification on my app on the main viewController. My problem is that the system seems to be the catch it in `didRecieveLocalNotification` which I am but I then need to take some action in the main view.

My problem is that that action differs depending on a global class variable (Boolean) and from what I can tell the only way to access the viewController from the `didRecieveLocalNotification` is to recreate the view class as a new init alloc which would destroy the current value of said variable.

How do I call a viewController method from the `appdelegate`'s `didRecieveLocalNotification` without destroying the variable or any content on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the main viewController which you are referring to is the root view controller of your UIWindow which you should have in your app delegate, you can do the following.

```
[(viewController*)[self.window rootViewController] themethodyouwanttocall];
```

From the phrasing of your question, that should call a method on the root view controller from the app delegate.